# Joining 2 dictionary in python with specific value

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, dictionary

i tried to join this 2 dictionary

```
company_detail_list = {
    'Company 1': {
        'name': 'Company 1',
        'domain': 'Retail'
    },
    'Company 2': {
        'name': 'Company 2',
        'domain': 'Construction'
    }
}

employee_detail_list = {
    'John Doe': {
        'full_name': 'John Doe',
        'company': 'Company 1'
    },
    'Tom Smith': {
        'full_name': 'Tom Smith',
        'company': 'Company 2'
    }
}
```

now the problem is, how do i join 2 dictionary with key of "Company" to get "domain" from dict1 to make this output:

```
[{
    "full_name": "John Doe",
    "company": "Company 1",
    "domain": "Retail"
}, {
    "full_name": "Tom Smith",
    "company": "Company 2",
    "domain": "Construction"
}
}]
```

Thanks before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) and [`dict.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20update#dict.update) and create your `list` of `dict`s like the below:

```
lst = []
for k, v in employee_detail_list.items():
    dct_tmp = v
    dct_tmp.update({'domain' : company_detail_list.get(v['company'], {}).get('domain')})
    lst.append(dct_tmp)
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[
    {'full_name': 'John Doe', 'company': 'Company 1', 'domain': 'Retail'}, 
    {'full_name': 'Tom Smith', 'company': 'Company 2', 'domain': 'Construction'}
]
```

Comment: thanks dude, it's worked! how do i learn about this thing? any reference?

i will upvote and mark your answer

Comment: for knowing about this, you need to read about `dict`, and `dict.get()` and `dict.update()`. maybe thses links help you : [link_1](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_update.asp), [link_2](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp)

Comment: "How do I learn about this thing?" By doing tutorials, reading the documentation, and attempting to do "this thing". Asking on Stack Overflow without trying yourself isn't going to help you learn, and if you did try, you should show what you tried so you can learn _what you did wrong_. @FahmiSabilaDinnulhaq

Comment: I update the comment and add links, @PranavHosangadi says right, you can see tutorials and videos from youtube, and other things that he says.